# How do I write a vector that's moving down in scale towards zero

Tags: vectors

Please pardon my lack of proper etiquette here on this platform.

I'm trying to articulate an equation of a vector that's scaling down towards zero.

For example. In the movie "Honey I Shrunk the Kids". The kids were scaled down in size by some factor. If they kept scaling down further and further tending towards zero it could be thought of as distance. In this case zero is an infinity as it can never be reached because you can always scale down further more in size. Such a journey would move you towards the Planck length and then eventually past it as you journey further towards zero.

Thus how do you articulate such a thing in an equation?

Answer (score 3):

You could use different mathematical laws, the easiest $$l(t)=l(0)*\frac{1}{a*t+1} \text{  or  } l(t)=l(0)*e^{-a*t}, a>0$$ choosing a so to do it slow or fast.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm a little lost would it possible to identify what the parameters (variables) are here? Also how would you express this as a vector?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't leap in here, but I understood $l$ as being the $magnitude$ of any displacement vector in your image. So the image will be shrunk by the same factor in all directions. $t$ is time and $a$ is a constant that controls the rate at which shrinkage occurs.

Comment: what Philip said is what I also would say, just multiply your Vektors with my l(t) making l(0)=1

Comment: Sorry for any trouble but would it be possible to show the equation in an example?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t) \end{pmatrix}=e^{-a*t}*\begin{pmatrix} x(0)\\y(0)\\z(0) \end{pmatrix}$$ x,y,z your coordinates for the vector.